# How to register your application into\with Http.sys?

Tags: windows, namespaces, system, http.sys

So I created a TCP\HTTP server (IN C#). I want to give to it namespace on my 80's port near to other HTTP servers I have. How to do such thing (step - by step)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [HTTP Server Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364641%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in MSDN spec:

- Initialize HTTP service API, call [HttpInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364488%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- Register URLs with HTTP.SYS, call [HttpAddUrlToUrlGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364472%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- Receive a request, call [HttpReceiveHttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364495%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- Send a response, call [HttpSendHttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- Cleanup after urself, call [HttpRemoveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [HttpTerminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364506%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

There is a also a fully fledged application sample at [HTTP Server Sample Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364640%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

As you can clearly see, HTTP.SYS API is a C API intended for C applications. You shouldn't be using it from C#, and I'd recommend against pInvoking the entire API. Managed applications have the alternative of using [HTTP modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178468%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and extend the ASP.Net processing. This avenue will take care of many details needed in a  managed server, like activation, hosting, process monitoring and recycling and so on and so forth.

Comment: Is it possible to find real file with HTTP.SYS info for editing by hend *(or at least reading it) not using  Httpcfg.exe?

Comment: Httpcfg.exe is nothing but a thin shell around the HTTP Configuration API. Everything Httpcfg.exe can do is done via the API. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364455%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The way you would normally interact with http.sys is by registering an ISAPI DLL with IIS. [This is a good starting-point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at50e70y%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: So... Amm.. What shall I do Stp by Step? My HTTP\TCP server is written in C# so I realy do not get all that strange stuff...

Comment: You cannot directly register a C# application with ISAPI, but you could write a C++ ISAPI DLL that calls your C# code. I would recommend against that, though, and instead look at using HTTP Handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953. Step-by-step instructions are not really appropriate here, since there are *many* steps... but the links I've given you should be a good starting point.